# ArrayList to String - VS2008 - C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
  ArrayList filters = new ArrayList();
  filters.Add(new string[] { "Name", "Equals", "John" });


  ObjectDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("AppliedFilters", 
           string.Join(",",(string[])filters.ToArray(typeof(string))));
```

Am trying to add a parameter to my object data source which is bound to my select method which should accept a string[]. But as the SelectParameters.Add takes in (string,string) or the other 3 overloads which do not seem to function for me correctly.

The select method accepts a string param though i prefer it accept a string[] or arraylist, but for now I can live with accepting a string which i should convert back to string[]

Resolution:
followed this article [link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235166/how-do-i-set-up-objectdatasource-select-parameters-at-runtime)

**Closed** as duplicate of the question referenced above.

Comment: You should probably close this as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mistaken.

I suppose, this should be the code

`ObjectDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add(filters[0], filters[2));`

If you look at the MSDN Doc, it says the the 1st arg should be parameter name and 2nd arg should be parameter value.

Please read the doc carefully.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.parametercollection.add.aspx

Comment: shahkalpesh: The add has 4 overloads and i figured i would use this one
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dxsac270.aspx and create my param name called "AppliedFilters" and convert the arraylist to string

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you meant?

```
arrList.ToArray(typeof(string)) as string[];
```

Or are you trying to join strings together?

The mistake i think you're making here, is that I would split them up into three different variables, rather than putting them all in an array list. In your example:

```
var filterField = "Name";
var filterComparison = "Equals";
var filterValue = "John";
```

Comment: arronchick: The reason i used an ArrayList is that I can have multiple filters based and didn't want to restrict it to a single filter. I can have "name" "equals" "john" and an additional filter "Date" "<" "10/10/2008". This way my SelectMetjod gets a delimitted value that I can iterate.