# How to insert into ObjectDataSource a list of items from code behind , and NOT from the aspx?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, objectdatasource

I have the following declaration in my .ASPX :

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ODS" runat="server" 
    SelectMethod="GetPlayersData" DataObjectTypeName="DAL.MyObject">
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

How can I place the data in the ObjectDataSource from the code behind ?

This :

```
var items = MyFunctions.GetPlayersData().ToList<object>();
ODS.SelectParameters = (ParameterCollection)items;
```

Doesn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I set up ObjectDataSource select parameters at runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/235166/how-do-i-set-up-objectdatasource-select-parameters-at-runtime)

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/a/236420/1224069, you need to hook into the `OnSelecting` event and you can set the params there.

Comment: @ Philip Pittle: You didn't understand me , I need to put the entire list in the ObjectDataSource , the link you provided doesn't show how to put an entire list or collection in ObjectDataSource , only sets the parameters names .

Comment: `SelectParameters` doesn't have a setter, you can't set the list directly.  You'd have to iterate `items` and call `ODS.SelectParameters.Add()` for each one.  But as the Select Parameters are only consumed in the `Selecting` event, it makes sense to set `SelectParameters` in an event handler.   Scott Mitchell has a nice tutorial on this topic here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa581787.aspx

Comment: Or are you trying to say that you want an instance of a List to be passed as a single Select Parameter?  Or you don't want to use an ObjectDataSource at all?  You just want to directly bind `items` to a Control (ie GridView?):  `myGridViewd.DataSource = items;  myGridView.DataBind();`

Comment: @Philip Pittle: Exactly , just take I want to put the entire items from the .aspx.cs .

Answer (score 1):

If I understand that you want to call `DAL.MyObject.GetPlayersData()` and get that data to a data bound control, you don't necessarily need an `ObjectDataSource`.  You can simply wire the data into the [DataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basedatalist.datasource(v=vs.110).aspx) property and then call the [DataBind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkx0cy6d(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
 GridView myGridView;
 //Set Data Source
 myGridView.DataSource = DAL.MyObject.GetPlayersData();
 //Have GridView pull in the data.
 myGridView.DataBind();
```

Alternatively, if you still want to use some of the features of `ObjectDataSource` to make two way data binding nicer, you can build up a `ObjectDataSource` programatically in your code behind.  The process is very similiar to the declarative syntax:

```
  ODS.SelectMethod = "GetPlayersData",
  ODS.DataObjectTypeName = "DAL.MyObject",
  ODS.TypeName = "MyFunctions"
```

The `ObjectDataSource` will call `GetPlayersData()` itself, so you don't need to call it yourself.

But if for some odd reason you need to, you can override the [ReturnValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasourcestatuseventargs.returnvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) in the [Selected](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasource.selected(v=vs.110).aspx) event:

```
 ods.Selected += (sender, args) =>
 {
   //This will cause GetPlayersData() to be called twice
   args.ReturnValue = MyFunctions.GetPlayersData();
 }
```